# Permanently update html element within Elementor / Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm looking to update a number on a success page and permanently change the number so that new visitors get the updated number. The site is build in Wordpress. The route with localStorage would not work as the updated number is then not visible to new visitors.

Do you have a solution how to update the ID element permanently? Do I need to use a PHP function?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

let signUpCounter = document.querySelector("#sign-up-counter");

if (signUpCounter) {
function countUpByOne(start, end) {
    var current = start;
    setInterval(function () {
        // current += 1;
        current++;
        signUpCounter.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            current = start;
        }
    }, 10000);
}
}

countUpByOne(7000, 15000);

});
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Store in DB (could be in options table with `add_options`) and get it from there.

Comment: @HarpreetSIngh yes,  but how would you do that exactly:/

Comment: Something like this.. On success page when you increment counter use `update_option( 'increment', $counter);` and then on the page where you want to show it up.. use `get_option('increment');`